# Как отслеживать изменения в файле, произошедшие извне процесса (out-of-process)?

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, файловая-система, индексация

Я пишу систему для индексации контента текстовых файлов на .NET. Система наблюдает за изменениями в файлах через `FileSystemWatcher` и по событию запускает процесс актуализации индекса.

Очевидно, при изменении файла переиндексировать файл целиком — это плохое решение, т.к. файл может оказаться большим. Хочется, чтобы время, затраченное на переиндексацию зависело от количества изменений, а не от размера файла.

Вопрос в том, как быстро определить, в каком месте файл был изменён? Вычислять diff между версиями файла — это слишком ресурсоёмкое решение.

Я думал сделать так:

1. Разбить файл на части по несколько килобайт
2. Вычислить дайджесты (хэши) от каждой из частей (SHA-1 или MD5)
3. По событию изменения файла быстро сравнить дайджесты каждой из
   частей файла
4. Переиндексировать только изменившиеся части файла.

Здесь есть 2 проблемы:

1. Изменившаяся часть может содержать смещения на +/- N символов. Эти
   сдвиги влияют  оффсеты последующих частей файла, а значит и
   вычисленные хэши будут другие.
2. Хэш-функции дают коллизии, а значит нет гарантии, что совпадение
   дайджестов части файла означает, что исходные данные не были
   изменены.

Известны ли ещё какие-либо подходы для решения такой проблемы?
Может быть есть какой-нибудь вариант получить измененённые страницы файла от файловой системы?

Comment: Называется это file notifier, почитать можно на msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atwhk15d(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Указанный Вами пример — это приложение, фиксирующее факты изменения файла с помощью `FileSystemWatcher`. Ровно то же я и сам делаю. Но предоставляемые экземпляром класса `FileSystemWatcher` события не дают информации, что именно (или в какой месте в файле) произошли изменения, а мне именно это и необходимо.

Comment: С точки зрения файловой системы, дописывание чего-то в середину файла (или в начало) - это просто переписывание всего содержимого файла от точки изменения и до конца файла. Так что нет, нормального способа обнаружить изменения в текстовом файле нет.

Comment: Вы сможете узнать что изменилось, если вместе в индексом будете сохранять и индексируемый файл, это позволит вам сравнить новую и старую версию файла, т.е. сделать классический diff. Вот только не проще ли оптимизировать сам индексатор?

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, с индексатором как раз нет никаких проблем. Там нет другого пути, кроме просмотра индексируемого контента за O(n). Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы после получения сигнала об изменении в файле, не совершать лишнюю работу и не переиндексировать его целиком, а переиндексировать лишь то, что изменилось. Вычисление diff'а стоит, к сожалению, практически столько же, сколько и переиндексация всего файла.